# Java: Get executing jar path from soft link path

Tags: java

I have file structure like this. I would like to print the path of jar when i execute from soft link. But i am always getting actual location instead soft link location.

```
c:\MyDir\MySubDir
       MyJar.jar
c:\SoftLink1 --> c:\MyDir\MySubDir
c:\SoftLink2 --> c:\MyDir\MySubDir
```

When i print current jar file while executing MyJar.jar from SoftLink1 or SoftLink2 using below code, i am getting actual directory instead softlink location.

```
String path = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
```

What is the right way to print current jar file location (Soft link location) when i execute it from different soft links.

Comment: Pretty sure what you want is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

For a relative path:

```
System.getProperty("sun.java.command")
```